# How to retrieve with payload in Chrome DevTools Network

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to search response/request through keywords written in payload.
It's quite difficult to press and check every request.
Please let me know if there is a good way.

I want to search with any keyword that I cricled...
[image]

Comment: This would be a good feature so maybe you can suggest it on https://crbug.com.